# SQL Finding where drivers stop most

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables

route

- routeNo decimal
- routeName varchar

  //each route has multiple stops, each stop is store as a lat/lon

Stops:

- routeNo decimal
- stopNo  decimal
- latitude  decimal
- longitude decimal

and

//order has a route with stops

orderDelivery:

- routeNo  decimal
- stopNo  decimal
- orderNo decimal

//each driver has been assigned a route and a vehicle

workday:

- workday date
- driver char(9)
- route decimal 4,0
- vehicle char(7)

I need to find the list of drivers and their most frequent stop. I understand that I need to use some sort of join to locate all the data together returning their name along with their most frequent stop but am unsure how to implement it in code.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Post a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something along these lines:

```
SELECT t1.driver, t2.stopNo, t1.maxStop
FROM
(
    SELECT t.driver, MAX(t.stopCount) AS maxStop
    FROM
    (
        SELECT w.driver, s.stopNo, COUNT(s.stopNo) AS stopCount
        FROM workday w INNER JOIN Stops s ON w.route = s.routeNo
        INNER JOIN orderDelivery od ON s.routeNo = od.routeNo AND s.stopNo = od.stopNo
        GROUP BY w.driver, s.stopNo
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.driver
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT w.driver, s.stopNo, COUNT(s.stopNo) AS stopCount
    FROM workday w INNER JOIN Stops s ON w.route = s.routeNo
    INNER JOIN orderDelivery od ON s.routeNo = od.routeNo AND s.stopNo = od.stopNo
    GROUP BY w.driver, s.stopNo
) t2
ON t1.driver = t2.driver AND t1.maxStop = t2.stopCount
```

Comment: why the 2nd part of the group by?

Comment: @Drew Well the inner query will give you a temporary result set of drivers and the total number of stops.  But there is a secondary aggregation needed to find the _greatest_ number of stops, for each driver.

Comment: i haven't even looked at the inner, the derived. But coming out of it you have `t`. So why would you have `t.stopCount` in the group by?

Comment: I just updated.  If we were using SQL Server or Oracle, a common table expression would be doing wonders here.  Welcome to MySQL.